# Building coverage tool for chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking to extend dev tools in chrome to support 'what-just-ran'. Something like this - you click a record button, do something on the web page, and stop recording. In dev tools, it should show what part of the code ran - like dynamic code coverage. From what I read on the docs, there isn't any direct way. I have been hacking around with dev-front-end (source for developer tools) by setting breakpoints on every line and finding what line executed, that's about how far I could go. Is this project possible with current chrome extension APIs or even dev front end changes?

Answer (score 1):

**[JS heatmap profiler slash code coverage tool](http://heatfiler.qfox.nl/)** does that by preprocessing JavaScript.

[image: JS heatmap by Peter van der Zee]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Timeline screenshot]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline-files/timeline_slider_right.png))</sub>

Timeline has all of this plus rendering and loading information. Timeline data is exposed via [Remote debugging API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3) as well as any other data DevTools has.